Partial derivatives for functions with one complex variable
So far, suppose that we defined partial derivatives for functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.
In Cauchy-Riemann equations, for $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, we first view $f(z)$ as $f(z)= u(x+iy)+iv(x+iy)$ where $z= x+iy$, and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.
Then, in many textbooks, the authors always identify $u(x+iy)$ with $u(x,y)$ and $v(x+iy)$ with $v(x,y)$. For example, in Conway's book, he wrote $$\begin{align*}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h} &= \frac{f(x+h+iy)-f(x+iy)}{h} \newline &\substack{\dagger}{=} \frac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}{h}+i \frac{v(x+h,y)-v(x,y)}{h} \end{align*}$$
and take limits on both sides, we finally get $$f'(z)= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)$$
I am a person a little bit pedantic about the notation and don't like this ambiguous identification. So, my question is:
(1) If we accept the equation $\dagger$, they everything behind is compatible with the definition of partial derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But why $\dagger$ is true? For $f(z)$ the input is $\mathbb{C}$, but for the part on the right hand side of $\dagger$, the input is $\mathbb{R}^2$, they don't even have the same input! How to reconcile this problem? ( probably using the field isomorphism: $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a field with pairwise addition and the multiplication is defined as $(a, b)\cdot(c, d):=(ac-bd, ad+bc)$ ?)
(2) If we don't write the equation as $\dagger$ did, shall we define the partial derivative of a complex variate function as: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} (x,y):= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(x+h+iy)- u(x+iy)}{h}$$
Similar definitions for $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$.
Then we should say the notion of 'partial derivative' here is not exactly we used for functions $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, and it is just a symbol different from the partial derivative we have known.
Can somebody shed some light on this little problem? Which one should I accept?

What is $\mathbb{C}$ for you?

I tend to use the collection of all $a+bi$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, with addition and multiplication defined as $(a+bi)+(c+di)=(a+c)+(b+di)$, $(a+bi)\cdot (c+di)= (ac-bd)+ (ad+bc)i$

this hint is suggestive, maybe I just fixed this problem

If you want to be picky about notation, then I'm going to have to stop you at your second paragraph, where you say
$$f(z)= u(x+iy)+iv(x+iy).$$
This is not correct - you can check the beginning of the Wikipedia article. It's
$$f(x +iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y \text) \tag{*}$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
f &: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C \\
u &: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R \\
v &: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R \\
\end{align}
$$
Equation (*) is true, as an equality between complex numbers on both sides, and for all (real) $x$ and $y$ (where the functions are defined).
Now, we do use the shorthand $z = x+iy$. And there are also some facts that we use, that aren't very deep (they're just manipulating $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s), and might even be glossed over in some treatments, but are worth mentioning if we are being rigorous:

A limit of a complex valued function exists iff both the real and imaginary parts have limits

With the $z=x+iy$ shorthand (and in particular, $z_0 = x_0+iy_0$), then $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}$ exists iff $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)}$ exists, and they have the same value.


I think these should clarify most, if not all, of your concerns. Let me know if there's anything still left unclear.
